Create Leadership Only view on SharePoint teamsite calendar
I have a calendar on my teamsite that is used to request time off. Wondering if it is possible to have that calendar copy automatically to a leadership only view where we would add in things like lateness etc. without having to manually reenter the requests that went into the main calendar, and also making sure it is protected so the everyone can't see it.

You could use 2 separate calendars:

Create

Main Calendar: This is where all team members submit their time-off requests.
Leadership Calendar: This is where leadership can view the time-off requests and add additional notes like lateness, without other team members seeing this data.

Set Permissions on the Leadership Calendar:
Go to the Leadership Calendar settings.
Break the inheritance of permissions by going to "Settings" > "Permissions for this list" > "Stop Inheriting Permissions".
Remove permissions for all users except for those in the leadership group. Only leadership should have access to this calendar.

Set Up a Power Automate Flow to automatically copy events from the Main Calendar to the Leadership Calendar.

Use Views to customize calendar columns:
Main Calendar: Standard view showing all requests.
Leadership Calendar: Custom view that shows additional columns such as "Lateness" or other notes that leadership can use.


Option 2:
Alternatively you could have a look at Dataverse. There you can manage views and permissions more granularly.
